# C Allocating Memory in Loop: Error munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Tags: c, memory-leaks, dynamic-memory-allocation, undefined-behavior

I wrote a little test code that allocates memory and just seeing the result on valgrind when I free the pNumber variable.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int *pNumber = NULL;
static int s_array[10] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pNumber = (int*) malloc(100);
        pNumber = &s_array[i];
    }
    free(pNumber);
    pNumber = NULL;
    
    return 0;
}
```

However I get the error of "munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer", particularly the **pNumber = &s_array[i]** causes the error. However, when I change it to ***pNumber = s_array[i]**, the invalid pointer error is gone.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        pNumber = (int*) malloc(100);
        *pNumber = s_array[i];
    }
```

I'm just curious why pNumber = &s_array[i] would cause that error?

I thought I am freeing the pointer that has been allocated with malloc?

Comment: you first allocate memory and the result will be a pointer that can be freed. Then you overwrite this address with another one. And naturally the free() will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case the program has undefined behavior.

You are trying to free memory that you did not allocate.

```
free(pNumber);
```

because the pointer `pNumber` points to memory with the static storage duration.

```
pNumber = &s_array[i];
```

As for this statement

```
*pNumber = s_array[i];
```

then it sets the object pointed to by `pNumber` by the value of the expression `s_array[i]` and the pointer itself was not reassigned. It points to the dynamically allocated memory. So you may use the pointer to free the allocated memory.

That is in the first case you are reassigning the pointer itself loosing the address of the dynamically allocated memory and trying to free an object with the static storage duration. As a result there are memory leaks and undefined behavior.

In the second case you just set a value to the allocated memory. So the program only produces numerous memory leaks.

Comment: Inside the for loop, should I free the memory as soon as I'm done with it? Or is there a way to free the memory outside of the loop?

Comment: @Lebronfan23 Outside the loop you can free only the last allocated extent of memory because inside the loop the pointer is reassigned in each iteration of the loop The addresses of the previously allocated memory will be lost.

Comment: In other words - in order to be able to free the memory outside the loop, you need to store the pointer to the memory somewhere (for example in an array of pointers).